# setText() nullPointer exception for text view

Tags: android, user-interface, textview

I want to refresh after all drags ended. However, I get `NullPointerException` even if I have the number. Also, I do `setContentView()` to demanded one. I think I have different problem. Code of the `Fragment` is the following:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
     System.out.println(String.valueOf(newGame.getPlayer(1).getHand().getHandSize()));
     kyleNum.setText(String.valueOf(newGame.getPlayer(1).getHand().getHandSize()));
break;
```

My crash Log is:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                  at android.example.com.sevens.GameActivity$MyDragListener.onDrag(GameActivity.java:413)
                  at android.view.View.dispatchDragEvent(View.java:19809)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1423)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1423)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1423)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1423)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1423)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1423)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleDragEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5488)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.access$1000(ViewRootImpl.java:108)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3624)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? Where do you get TextView: kyleNum?

Comment: you are not creating **kyleNum** object thats why you getting null pointer exception.

Comment: You can put a try-catch block to debug or put a != null check to check if your object exists

Comment: It has no problem with initialization or etc. Code is very big so that I didnt want to share

Comment: Share your crash log

Comment: Put more relevant code to get help faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if your `TextView` lives inside the `Fragment` just do this for your code to work:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
            false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText("Teststring");
    return rootView;
}
```